# python-asyncio/aiohttp: RuntimeError "Event loop is closed"

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

My python script contains the following code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from time import time


def write_img(data):
    cnt = str(time()/60/60)
    filename = f"filename-{cnt}.jpeg"
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(data)


async def fetch_cont(url, session):
    async with session.get(url, allow_redirects=True) as response:
        data = await response.read()
        write_img(data)


async def main():
    url = "https://loremflickr.com/320/240"
    tasks = []

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(11):
            task = asyncio.create_task(fetch_cont(url, session))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This script works correctly, but it throws the following errors during execution:

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000195E74BA550>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rhan1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\rhan1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\rhan1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 715, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\rhan1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

How to catch exceptions correctly to handle errors or how to fix them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not *super* familiar with `asyncio`, but from my understanding, one has to grab the main event loop (`loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`), construct your task list (which you've done), and then run these tasks in your loop with something like `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))`

Comment: with what @monica said, there is also a bug, see https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324

Comment: latest issue was 23 days ago

Comment: Try to move the `asyncio.gather ` function out of the context  manager for `aiohttp ` session

Comment: when I tried to run this code it did not raise any errors :/

Comment: This is a known issue in aiohttp as per https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324.